# MySQL Partitioning user generated rows by user

Tags: mysql, partitioning

I have two tables: **userMessages** and **userStatistics**

I realized that I need to set up a partitioning in order to ensure efficiency. With all the information I could gather, I am suppose to use HASH partitioning.

```
PARTITION BY HASH(user_id) PARTITIONS 101
```

Why do I have to define number of partitions? Is it possible to partition by number of users? I want to partition all the messages and statistics by each user. What partitions number should I use?

---

### More Context

Let use my **userStatistics** for example. This will store a new entry every day to capture daily activity of users impressions and click-throughs etc... I expect this database to get very large over time. I expect it to be very large within a year (>1m rows). I was thinking of just creating separate tables for each user using an index, but was told about partitioning using HASH. What is the best way to approach this case?

Comment: You have to define Partition number for `HASH` partitioning as it is equally distributes data in partitions. If you want to separate data by UserID try using `Range Partition`

Answer (score 0):

Partition by `HASH` will not provide any efficiency.  In fact, there are only a few `RANGE` partitionings that provide any efficiency.  I suspect your use case does not apply.  See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint

Describe your use case further if you would like to debate the issue.

Comment: Please see above, I will describe the context on my situation

Comment: Please provide tentative `SELECT` statements.